# UIDataDetectorTypeLink in UICollectionView causing problems

Tags: ios, objective-c, hyperlink, uicollectionview

I have a uitextview with UIDataDetectorTypeLink in a uicollectionviewcell. When I come across an item with a link, that link starts to appear in every other cell - even when there is no link in that item, and it's the same link over and over again.

I've tried setting the data detector type to none when there is no link data in an item, but that just disables the ones that have the link data. I've also tried setting the text to nil, but it didn't do anything.

I'm not sure what to do. Is this a bug in iOS7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `TTTAttributedLabel` to solve my problem.